# Globbing fails in zsh, but works in bash

Tags: grep, zsh, wildcards

I have an alias in bash, that I'm trying to port over to zsh. I thought it may have been the alias itself, but now it seems it's just the globbing.

```
grep -irl --exclude=\*.{log,class,fuegoclass,dat}* --exclude-dir={build,system,lib} data
```

What's the right way to exclude these file extensions and directories in zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
grep -irl --exclude=\*.{log,class,fuegoclass,dat}* --exclude-dir={build,system,lib} data
```

In both `zsh` and `bash`, `--exclude=\*.{log,class,fuegoclass,dat}*` expands first to `--exclude=\*.log* --exclude=\*.class* --exclude=\*.fuegoclass* --exclude=\*.dat*` and then, because of the unquoted `*`, each is treated as a pattern to perform globbing on.

For instance, `--exclude=\*.log*` will expand to the list of files in the current directory whose name starts with `--exclude=*.log`.

If any of the globs has no match, in `zsh`, the command will be aborted. In `bash`, the globs will expand to themselves.

Here, you don't want globbing so you should quote all the globbing characters (in both `zsh` and `bash`, `zsh` is just kind enough to point your mistake to you).

```
grep -irl --exclude=\*.{log,class,fuegoclass,dat}\* --exclude-dir={build,system,lib} data
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to make sure I understand, the problem was with the last asterisk? Bash forgave the error and zsh does not?

Comment: @jktravis, yes, the problem was the last asterisk which made those arguments globs. `zsh` causes a visible error when the glob doesn't match. `bash` would have caused a hard to detect error had the glob matched.